# Как установить пакет в Termux?

Tags: termux

**Приветсвую! Начал изучать Termux, и сразу началась трудности; Пытаюсь установить пакет:'git':**

$pkg install git

Checking availability of current mirror: ok

Reading packeg list... Done

Building dependancy tree... Done

И появляеться проблема:

E: Unable to locate package git

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй

```
pkg update
pkg upgrade
pkg install git
```

или

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install git
```

Comment: Спасибо , сработало